# Расположить кнопки на одном уровне

Tags: css, bootstrap

Вторая кнопка чуть ниже первой. Как расположить на одном уровне?

```
<div class="col-md-12" >
<a type="button" class="button" target=blank href="">Кнопка1</a>
<button type="button" class="button" >Кнопка2</button>      
</div>
```

Comment: `d-flex align-items-center`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-md-6" >
  <a class="button" target="_blank" href="#">Кнопка 1</a> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" >
  <button type="button" class="button">Кнопка 2</button>      
</div>
```

Мы не видим результат который Вам надо получить. Но в целом, это, скорее всего, 2 колонки.